# gaussian kernel and bionomial coefficients

Tags: gaussian

The following image is from robert collins' ppt from http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rcollins/CSE486/

How to calculate sigma ?

It shows [1 4 6 4 1] is corresponding to sigma=1.

I learned that usually 3*sigma is best to represent. So kernel size is 7*7 is suited. But its size is 5*5.

I don't know why [1 4 6 4 1] is matched to sigma=1.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The well-known twentieth-century American columnist Dorothy Parker once reviewed a book 
saying

> "This is not a book to be put down lightly; it should be thrown with great force."

Be that as it may, Professor Collins is suggesting that a bar plot of the binomial
coefficients on the $n$-th row of Pacal's triangle, after suitable normalization,
will look from far away like a Gaussian distribution with mean $n/2$ and standard
deviation $\sqrt{n}/2$.  He then further obfuscates this by using the fact that for
*even* values of $n$, we can write the standard deviation as $\sqrt{k/2}$
where $k = n/2$
while for *odd* $n$, it is simply $\sqrt{n}/2$, inviting the reader to arrive at
the mistaken conclusion that there is a fundamental difference between the odd
and even rows.

To get a better understanding of where the $n/2$ and $\sqrt{n}/2$
comes from, look for reading material on the *DeMoivre-LaPlace approximation*
which is a special case of the *Central Limit Theorem*.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm a novice and your advice is impressing for me. I am somewhat confused but I'll study!

Comment: $\sigma^2$ =(approximate) npq, where p=1/2 and q=1/2. So $\sigma = \sqrt{npq} = \sqrt n / 2$ Am I right?

Comment: $\sigma^2$ **equals** $npq$, not $\sigma^2 \approx npq$, but yes, that is why we get $\sqrt{n}/2$.

Comment: Thank you. There are still many things I don't understand. It is hard for me.